# How to create action to search button in keyboard?

Tags: iphone, search, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have three text fields in one page, when the textfield is empty, then the keyboard should show return keyboard, otherwise it should show search, and by clicking on that search button we need to go to another view controller. can any explain with sample code?

Answer (score 4):

Set `delegate` of your `UITextField` and them implement `delegate` function

To show `search` and `return` key

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        textField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDefault;
    }
    else{
        textField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeySearch;
    }
}
```

Coding on keyboard return button

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.returnKeyType==UIReturnKeyDefault)
    {
        //Your Return Key code
    }
    else if(textField.returnKeyType==UIReturnKeySearch)
    {
        //Your search key code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.